# Specifying img src and associating a class using innerHTML in a javascript code

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the code below to create an image with a css class and put it in a div (`imagepath1`) .

```
this.imagePath1.innerHTML = "<img src='" + "../path/imagename" + "' class='classname'>";
```

It is not able to find the image path, as I can see in the DOM element and resource is also not available when seen through "inspect element".

Any clues how to do this?

Thanks,
kk

Comment: Well if the inspected code looks OK then there must be a problem with the URL of the image. Does it work?

Comment: Depending on your doctype the markup may be invalid. Close the `<img/>` tag.

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it.

Comment: what is the actual image path that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

1)Be sure the path you are coding is relative to your html document ( not to your javascript document)

2) The img tag is fine without closing slash for html (no closing tag in  is ok for HTML  but some browser may use the XHTML syntax where the  tag must be properly closed.

**NOTE**

*Both possible solutions are made under the consideration that your **javascript statement** is in the correct context concerning the use of the **this** keyword.* which as you know, is related to the caller and context and not to the function.

Comment: It seems to be working after I gave the full path of the image:)